# Does Installer Need an Internet Connection?

Tags: python-2.7, installation

I have a Windows machine that I want to install `Python (2.7)` on.
That machine is not connected to the internet and never will be.
Hence the question: If I download the thing that the python site
calls the installer and copy it to that machine, will that be
enough to install python? Or does the installer need internet
access, like so many "installers" these days?

(Yes, I could just try it. Got a very slow connection...)

Anyone happens to know the answer to the same question regarding
wxpython that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean python installer for windows, yes it's enough and installer doesn't need internet connection, but if you want to install another modules through pip you will need internet connection.